# How to populate listview with QStringList?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am developing an app which is to find all the mp4 videos in the sdcard and list them in the listview. A button is made to play all the video in the list or clicking one of the video list is able to play that video.

I don't know how to implement the linking between the QStringlist in C++ and the folderModel in QML. Maybe it should use another way to populate the listview with QStringlist. I have implemented the search part of the mp4 files in C++ side, but don't know how to make the listview populated with that QStringlist which stored the filepath of mp4 videos. Please help.

The source code:

**filemodel.cpp**

```
#ifndef FILEMODEL_H
#define FILEMODEL_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QDirIterator>
#include <QString>

class MyObject : public QObject{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyObject (QObject* parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}
    Q_INVOKABLE QStringList findfile();
};


QStringList MyObject::findfile( ) {
    QStringList all_dirs;
    QDirIterator it(dir, QStringList() << "*.mp4", QDir::Files, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
    while (it.hasNext()){
        all_dirs << it.next();
    }
}

#endif // FILEMODEL_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    MyObject obj;
    engine.rootCtontext()->setContextProperty("MyObject", &obj);
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.1
import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.1
import QtMultimedia 5.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import Qt.labs.platform 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")        

    SwipeView {
        id: swipeView
        anchors.fill: parent
        currentIndex: tabBar.currentIndex

        Page1 {            
            ListView {
                width: 200; height: 400

                FolderListModel {
                    id: folderModel
                    nameFilters: ["*.mp4"]
                }

                Component {
                    id: fileDelegate
                    Text { text: fileName }
                }

                model: folderModel
                delegate: fileDelegate
            }

            Button {
                id: button

                width: parent.width
                text: "Play"
                background: Rectangle {
                    implicitHeight: 40
                    border.color: "#26282a"
                    border.width: 2
                    radius: 4
                }
                onClicked:
                {
                    player.source = folderModel.get (0, "fileURL")
                    playTimer.start()
                    player.play()
                    swipeView.setCurrentIndex(1)
                }
            }
        }

        Page {
            MediaPlayer {
                id: player
            }

            VideoOutput {
                    id: video
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    source: player
            }
        }
    }

    function setImageIndex(i)
    {
        index = i;
        if (index >= 0 && index < folderModel.count){
            player.source = folderModel.get (index, "fileURL");
            player.play();
        }
        else{
            player.source = folderModel.get (index, "fileURL");
            player.play();
        }
    }

    Timer {
        id: playTimer
        interval: 2000
        repeat: true
        running: true
        onTriggered: {
            var source_name = player.source;

            if(source_name.toString().indexOf(".mp4")>0){ //processing .mp4
                if (player.status == MediaPlayer.EndOfMedia){
                    if (index + 1 < folderModel.count){
                        setImageIndex(index + 1);
                    }
                    else{
                        index = 0;
                        setImageIndex(index);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     }

    footer: TabBar {
        id: tabBar
        currentIndex: swipeView.currentIndex
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("First")
        }
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("Second")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why implement the search on the C ++ side? FolderListModel must do it directly in the .qml

Comment: I am not sure if using folderlistmodel is correct. But it is a good way to implement search on the C ++ side, since I don't know other method better than that.

Comment: FolderListModel implements this filter and in your qml code it is already implemented: `nameFilters: ["*.mp4"]`,  
Why do you want to do the search in C ++? What is your main objective?

Comment: Also the declaration of a variable of type `QList <QFileInfo>` is not supported in qml, I think you should have many syntactic errors.

Comment: I want a listview that is full of .mp4 found in the sdcard, so that part is finished by using the QDirIterator. And those videos can be further played. The FolderListModel can only filter it in a single folder. Maybe I shouldn't use folderlistmodel. The QList <QFileInfo> is a mistake and is corrected.

Comment: you must create your own model, for example using QStringListModel. do not use folderlistmodel

Comment: What information of the files do you want to show?

Comment: I want to show their filename in the listview, but can be played each by clicking them afterwards or played all by clicking a button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use `FolderListModel` if you want to make your own filter from C ++, to do it there are several possibilities.

1. one of them is to implement your own model for it, we create a class that inherits from `QAbstractListModel`:

---

```
#ifndef FILEMODEL_H
#define FILEMODEL_H

#include <QAbstractListModel>
#include <QDirIterator>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QMetaType>
#include <QFuture>
#include <QtConcurrent>

struct File
{
    Q_GADGET
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name MEMBER name)
    Q_PROPERTY(QUrl url MEMBER url)
public:
    QString name;
    QUrl url;
    File(const QString& name=""){
        this->name = QFileInfo(name).fileName();
        this->url = QUrl::fromLocalFile(name);
    }
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(File)

class FileModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    enum dashBoardRoles {
        NameRole=Qt::UserRole+1,
        URLRole
    };
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString folder READ folder WRITE setFolder NOTIFY folderChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QStringList nameFilters READ nameFilters WRITE setNameFilters NOTIFY nameFiltersChanged)
public:
    FileModel(QObject *parent=Q_NULLPTR):QAbstractListModel(parent){
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE QVariant get(int index){
        return QVariant::fromValue(m_all_dirs[index]);
    }

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent=QModelIndex()) const{
        Q_UNUSED(parent)
        return m_all_dirs.count();
    }
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const{
        if(index.row()<0 && index.row()>= rowCount())
            return QVariant();
        File  file = m_all_dirs[index.row()];
        if(role == NameRole)
            return file.name;
        else if(role == URLRole)
            return file.url;
        return QVariant();
    }

    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const {
        QHash <int,QByteArray> roles;
        roles [NameRole]="fileName";
        roles [URLRole]="url";
        return roles;
    }

    QString folder() const{
        return mFolder;
    }

    void setFolder(const QString &folder)
    {
        if(mFolder == folder)
            return;
        mFolder = folder;
        emit folderChanged();
        findFiles();
    }

    QStringList nameFilters() const{
        return mNameFilters;
    }

    void setNameFilters(const QStringList &nameFilters){
        if(mNameFilters == nameFilters)
            return;
        mNameFilters = nameFilters;
        emit nameFiltersChanged();
        findFiles();
    }

signals:
    void folderChanged();
    void nameFiltersChanged();

private:
    void findFiles(){

        beginResetModel();
        m_all_dirs.clear();
        if(QDir(mFolder).exists()){
            QFuture<QStringList> future = QtConcurrent::run([=]() {
                QStringList files;
                QDirIterator it(mFolder, mNameFilters, QDir::Files, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
                while (it.hasNext()){
                    files<<it.next();
                }
                return files;
            });
            QStringList fullNames = future.result();
            for(const QString& fullName: fullNames){
                File file{fullName};
                m_all_dirs << file;
            }
        }
        endResetModel();
    }
    QString mFolder;
    QList<File> m_all_dirs;
    QStringList mNameFilters;
};

#endif // FILEMODEL_H
```

and then it is registered and used in the .qml

**main.cpp**

```
qmlRegisterType<FileModel>("com.eyllanesc.filemodel", 1,0, "FileModel");
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtMultimedia 5.8

import com.eyllanesc.filemodel 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Tabs")

    SwipeView {
        id: swipeView
        anchors.fill: parent
        currentIndex: tabBar.currentIndex

        Page {

            ListView {
                id: lv
                width: 200; height: 400

                Component {
                    id: fileDelegate
                    Text { text: fileName
                        MouseArea{
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            onClicked: playMusic(index)
                        }
                    }
                }

                model: FileModel{
                    id: myModel
                    folder: "/home/eyllanesc"
                    nameFilters: ["*.mp4"]
                }

                delegate: fileDelegate
            }

            Button {
                id: button
                anchors.top: lv.bottom
                width: parent.width
                text: "Play"
                background: Rectangle {
                    implicitHeight: 40
                    border.color: "#26282a"
                    border.width: 2
                    radius: 4
                }
                onClicked: playMusic(0)
            }
        }

        Page {
            MediaPlayer {
                id: player
                onStopped: {
                    if(status===MediaPlayer.EndOfMedia){
                        playMusic((lv.currentIndex+1) % lv.count)
                    }
                }
            }

            VideoOutput {
                id: video
                anchors.fill: parent
                source: player
            }
        }
    }

    function playMusic(index){
        player.stop()
        player.source = myModel.get(index).url
        player.play()
        swipeView.setCurrentIndex(1)
    }

    footer: TabBar {
        id: tabBar
        currentIndex: swipeView.currentIndex

        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("Page 1")
        }
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("Page 2")
        }
    }
}
```

2. The other solution is to use `QQmlListProperty` and expose those properties:

---

```
#ifndef FILEMANAGER_H
#define FILEMANAGER_H

#include <QDirIterator>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QFuture>
#include <QObject>
#include <QQmlListProperty>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QVector>
#include <QtConcurrent>

class File: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString fileName READ fileName CONSTANT)
    Q_PROPERTY(QUrl url READ url CONSTANT)
public:
    File(const QString fullPath="", QObject *parent = nullptr):QObject(parent){
        mFullPath = fullPath;
    }
    QString fileName() const
    {
        return QFileInfo(mFullPath).fileName();
    }
    QUrl url() const{
        return QUrl::fromLocalFile(mFullPath);
    }

private:
    QString mFullPath;
};

class FileManager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<File> files READ files NOTIFY filesChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString folder READ folder WRITE setFolder NOTIFY folderChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QStringList nameFilters READ nameFilters WRITE setNameFilters NOTIFY nameFiltersChanged)
public:
    explicit FileManager(QObject *parent = nullptr):QObject(parent){}
    QQmlListProperty<File> files(){
        return QQmlListProperty<File>(this, this,
                                      &FileManager::filesCount,
                                      &FileManager::file);
    }

    QString folder() const
    {
        return mFolder;
    }

    void setFolder(const QString &folder)
    {
        if(mFolder == folder)
            return;
        mFolder = folder;
        emit folderChanged();
        findFiles();
    }

    int filesCount() const{
        return mFiles.count();
    }

    File *file(int index) const{
        return mFiles.at(index);
    }
    QStringList nameFilters() const{
        return mNameFilters;
    }

    void setNameFilters(const QStringList &nameFilters){
        if(mNameFilters == nameFilters)
            return;
        mNameFilters = nameFilters;
        emit nameFiltersChanged();
        findFiles();
    }

signals:
    void folderChanged();
    void filesChanged();
    void nameFiltersChanged();
private:

    void findFiles( ) {
        mFiles.clear();
        if(QDir(mFolder).exists()){
            QFuture<QStringList> future = QtConcurrent::run([=]() {
                QStringList files;
                QDirIterator it(mFolder, mNameFilters, QDir::Files, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
                while (it.hasNext()){
                    files<<it.next();
                }
                return files;
            });

            for(const QString& fullName:  future.result()){
                File* file = new File(fullName);
                mFiles << file;
            }
        }
        emit filesChanged();
    }

    static int filesCount(QQmlListProperty<File>* list){
        return reinterpret_cast<FileManager* >(list->data)->filesCount();
    }
    static File* file(QQmlListProperty<File>* list, int index){
        return reinterpret_cast<FileManager* >(list->data)->file(index);
    }
    QVector<File *> mFiles;
    QString mFolder;
    QStringList mNameFilters;
};

#endif // FILEMANAGER_H
```

and then it is registered and used in the .qml

**main.cpp**

```
qmlRegisterType<FileManager>("com.eyllanesc.filemanager", 1,0, "FileManager");
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtMultimedia 5.8

import com.eyllanesc.filemanager 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Tabs")

    FileManager{
        id: manager
        folder: "/home/eyllanesc"
        nameFilters: ["*.mp4"]
    }

    SwipeView {
        id: swipeView
        anchors.fill: parent
        currentIndex: tabBar.currentIndex

        Page {

            ListView {
                id: lv
                width: 200; height: 400

                Component {
                    id: fileDelegate
                    Text { text: fileName
                        MouseArea{
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            onClicked: playMusic(index)
                        }
                    }
                }

                model: manager.files
                delegate: fileDelegate
            }

            Button {
                id: button
                anchors.top: lv.bottom
                width: parent.width
                text: "Play"
                background: Rectangle {
                    implicitHeight: 40
                    border.color: "#26282a"
                    border.width: 2
                    radius: 4
                }
                onClicked: playMusic(0)
            }
        }

        Page {
            MediaPlayer {
                id: player
                onStopped: {
                    if(status===MediaPlayer.EndOfMedia){
                        playMusic((lv.currentIndex+1) % lv.count)
                    }
                }
            }

            VideoOutput {
                id: video
                anchors.fill: parent
                source: player
            }
        }
    }

    function playMusic(index){
        player.stop()
        player.source = manager.files[index].url
        player.play()
        swipeView.setCurrentIndex(1)
    }

    footer: TabBar {
        id: tabBar
        currentIndex: swipeView.currentIndex

        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("Page 1")
        }
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("Page 2")
        }
    }
}
```

Both examples can be found in the following links

- https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/48534529-1
- https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/48534529-2

Comment: Thank you very much. I couldn't write such code at the present level. Would you mind recommending any resources for me to look up to advance my QT skill?

Comment: Excuse me. Could you show how to use keyboard to control the application? I have difficulty to do such thing. Please help me. I have spent three days on doing that.

Comment: My verison is placed at here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48619151/how-to-use-the-key-navigation-of-qml?noredirect=1#comment84276324_48619151